# How can I unpivot three types of values (including the column headers)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

The data I have looks like this:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ option1 ║ option2 ║ option3 ║ percent_opt1 ║ percent_opt2 ║ percent_opt3 ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 10      ║ 4       ║ 1       ║ 0.67         ║ 0.27         ║ 0.07         ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

So if i want to make the first three column headers row values, then the other ones also as more row values, how would I do that?

This is what I mean:

```
╔═════════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ options ║ values ║ percentages ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║ option1 ║ 10     ║ 0.67        ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║ option2 ║ 4      ║ 0.27        ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║ option3 ║ 1      ║ 0.07        ║
╚═════════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
declare @tbl as table (
    option1 numeric(18,0),
    option2 numeric(18,0),
    option3 numeric(18,0),
    per_opt1 numeric(18,2),
    per_opt2 numeric(18,2),
    per_opt3 numeric(18,2)
)

insert into @tbl
values (10,4,1,0.67,0.27,0.07)

;

select * from
(
    select t.[option1],t.[option2],t.[option3]
    from @tbl as t
) as srctbl
    unpivot (
        val for options in (option1,option2,option3)
) as unpiv
```

I don't know how to get those last three percentage column values to be row values, partially because I can't have a different datatype, and because I'm not sure how to.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
select v.*
from @tbl t cross apply
     (values ('option1', option1, percent_opt1),
             ('option2', option2, percent_opt2),
             ('option3', option3, percent_opt3)
     ) v(option, value, percent_opt);
```

Note:  `values` is a SQL keyword so I changed the name of the middle column.

In my opinion, there is no reason whatsoever to learn `unpivot`.  It is bespoke functionality -- extensions in a small number of databases -- that does just one thing in an "okay" way.

On the other hand, `apply` supports *lateral joins*, which are standard (even if the syntax varies among databases).  They are very powerful, and unpivoting is a good way to start learning about them.

Comment: wow thanks for the quick answer! it's exactly what i need. I was wondering if there was even a way to do this with just pivots out of curiosity. i couldn't figure it out. I'm trying to practice them. is there even a way to do it like that?

Answer (score 3):

Use a lateral join - in SQL Server this is called `apply`:

```
select x.*
from @tbl t
cross apply (values
    ('option1', t.option1, t.per_opt1),
    ('option2', t.option2, t.per_opt2),
    ('option3', t.option3, t.per_opt3)
) as x(options, vals, percentages)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d48805ed57e52d9320be30126abc4918)**:

```
options | vals | percentages
:------ | ---: | ----------:
option1 |   10 |        0.67
option2 |    4 |        0.27
option3 |    1 |        0.07
```

Note that `values` is a SQL keyword - I renamed the column to `vals` in the resultset.